# Add days in date in yyyymmdd format SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a hard-coded date in a variable in yyyymmdd format

```
DECLARE @StartDate = 20160101;
```

Now I want to add 365 days in this date.

When I do this 20160101 + 365, it gives incorrect output 20160466, it should give me answer after adding 365 days which I think is 20160102

Please tell me how to do it in SQL server in DECLARE variable ? I want output in yyyymmdd format

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: Errr... no: you have a hard-coded integer.

Comment: There should be a way, to make it in other format with substring and then add days and then convert back using substring ? as we know first 4 digits will always be year etc

Comment: SQL Server has data types **designed** for dealing with dates. If you choose not to use them, don't be surprised where it doesn't have support for performing date operations on a different data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StartDate INT = '20161117';
select convert(varchar,CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(8),@StartDate))+365,112)
```

Comment: I tried like this                                                                                                                           DECLARE @StartDate INT = 20161117;

select convert(varchar,cast(@StartDate as datetime)+365,112). I gives this error Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: I want to keep the @starfDays in INT if possible

Comment: Please use `DATEADD` instead. This rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: how. I want to do like this DECLARE @StartDate INT = 20161117;

select convert(varchar,cast(@StartDate as datetime)+365,112) but it gives error.

Comment: @Aiden You can't expect an INT to work with DATE logic. This is why there's a thing as DATE/DATETIME/DATETIME2 in SQL. You can convert back to INT afterwards if you so desire.

Comment: How is this answer even doing any addition at all. It's already included in the starting INT value. What?

Comment: Great but where did +365 go ? LOL

Comment: Why have you added 366 instead of 365 ? I want to add 365 days in that date.

Comment: @Aiden, why do you accept answers that are absolutely not working? Sigh.

Comment: @Jens, it works, I just ran it in my sql server. What is wrong with it? I have to INSERT this into an INTEGER column in database, that is why I wanted it to be INT

Answer (score 1):

Put the date in quotes and then use `DATEADD`:

```
DECLARE @StartDate = '2016-01-01';

SELECT DATEADD (day, 365, @StartDate)
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: I want it as INT   DECLARE @StartDate INT = 20161117; select convert(varchar,cast(@StartDate as datetime)+365,112) but it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Date DATE= '20160101'SELECT DATEADD(DAY,365,@Date)

FOR INT DATA TYPE :
DECLARE @Date INT = '20160101'
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,365,CONVERT (DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(8),@Date)))
```

Comment: I want to keep the @starfDays in INT if possible

Comment: @Aiden Yes possible

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE @StartDate INT = 20161117;

select cast(convert(varchar,cast(cast(@StartDate as varchar) as datetime)+366,112) as INT)